# Why doesn't Clang generate bitcode of some library functions in libstdc++?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++

When compiling this CPP file that using the `list` library by the command `clang++ list-simple-test.cpp -c -emit-llvm`:

```
// list1.cpp

#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int x = 1;

  list<int*> alist;
  alist.push_back(&x);

  return x;
}
```

I notice that some functions, like `_ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base7_M_hookEPS0_` is generated without a function body:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare dso_local void @_ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base7_M_hookEPS0_(%"struct.std::__detail::_List_node_base"*, %"struct.std::__detail::_List_node_base"*) #5
```

While most of the other functions are generated with a complete body, for example, like the function `_ZNSt7__cxx1110_List_baseIPiSaIS1_EE11_M_inc_sizeEm` below:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define linkonce_odr dso_local void @_ZNSt7__cxx1110_List_baseIPiSaIS1_EE11_M_inc_sizeEm(%"class.std::__cxx11::_List_base"*, i64) #1 comdat align 2 {
  %3 = alloca %"class.std::__cxx11::_List_base"*, align 8
  %4 = alloca i64, align 8
  store %"class.std::__cxx11::_List_base"* %0, %"class.std::__cxx11::_List_base"** %3, align 8
  store i64 %1, i64* %4, align 8
  %5 = load %"class.std::__cxx11::_List_base"*, %"class.std::__cxx11::_List_base"** %3, align 8
  %6 = load i64, i64* %4, align 8
  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %"class.std::__cxx11::_List_base", %"class.std::__cxx11::_List_base"* %5, i32 0, i32 0
  %8 = getelementptr inbounds %"struct.std::__cxx11::_List_base<int *, std::allocator<int *> >::_List_impl", %"struct.std::__cxx11::_List_base<int *, std::allocator<int *> >::_List_impl"* %7, i32 0, i32 0
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %"struct.std::__detail::_List_node_header", %"struct.std::__detail::_List_node_header"* %8, i32 0, i32 1
  %10 = load i64, i64* %9, align 8
  %11 = add i64 %10, %6
  store i64 %11, i64* %9, align 8
  ret void
}
```

I understand that those functions are from `libstdc++.so`. But why does Clang generate the body for some functions, but not the other?

Does anybody know how to make Clang generate the body of `_ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base7_M_hookEPS0_` as well?

Thank you very much for reading my question! I'm writing a static analysis tool, which needs to analyze the body of `_ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base7_M_hookEPS0_` to obtain more precise result.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably those other functions are coming from C++ templates.

When you declare a templated function, you have to provide its implementation in the header file in most cases. This way their code ends up in your own translation unit, and you see this code in your IR.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation. I believe the function `_ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base7_M_hookEPS0_` is from the `list` library. Is there any way that I can make Clang generate bitcode for it? I found a possible implementation of this `hook` function in here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/list.cc, but don't know why Clang doesn't generate bitcode for it.

Comment: For that you need to compile `libstdc++` with Clang and `-emit-llvm` flag, obviously. Maybe you can get away with just `clang++ -emit-llvm list.cc`.

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily found a workaround using the suggestion from @arrowd.

```
// generate list-simple-test.bc
clang++-list-simple-test.cpp -c -emit-llvm

// generate list.bc (list.cc is from the source code of libstdc++)
clang++ -emit-llvm list.cc

// combine list-simple-test.bc and list.bc
llvm-link list.bc list-simple-test.bc -o list-simple-final.bc
```

In the code about, `list.cc` can be downloaded from the [gcc project](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/list.cc)

The final bitcode file `list-simple-final.bc` will contain the definition of `_ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base7_M_hookEPS0_`, which is provided by `list.cc`